# AFrame: How to show a button when video (videosphere) ended?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, 360-virtual-reality

I am trying to detect whether a 360 video in mp4 format has ended before displaying a btn1 that was hidden.

```
<a-videosphere id="videosphere1"
    rotation="0 180 0"
    visible="true"
    src="#vid1"
    show-btn-when-ended="target: #btn1"
    autoplay = "true">
</a-videosphere>
```

Button to be displayed

```
<a-entity
            id="btn1"
            geometry = "primative: plane"
            position = "-0.8 3 -12.3"
            rotation = "0 -1 -3"
            scale = "12.5 25 1"
            visible = "false"
            text = "align:center; width: 6; wrapCount:100; color:black;
                    value: CLICK HERE"
            go-toScene-onCLick>
        </a-entity>
```

Script is not working. Unable to change attribute visible to true with javascript

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('show-btn-when-ended', {
init: function () {
    el = this.el;
    this.showBtn= this.showBtn.bind(this);
    el.addEventListener('ended', this.showBtn);
},

showBtn: function(evt) {
    console.log('in window.showBtn');
    var videosphere1 = document.querySelector("#videosphere1")
    var btn1 = document.querySelector('#btn1'); 
    btn1.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
    console.log("Show Button");

   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the A-Frame documentation, you should be able to listen for the `materialvideoended` event on the `<a-videosphere>` primitive.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/material.html#events_materialvideoended

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
videosphere1.addEventListener('materialvideoended', function() {
  // show button
});
```

I noticed that you were originally trying to pass in the `target` selector for the button through the component. You can do that by adding it to the schema of the component by doing something like below:

```
schema: {
  target: { type: 'selector', default: '[a-videosphere]' }
}
```

If no selector is defined, it will just default to the first `<a-videosphere>` primitive.